# Defining and extracting variable in Reguar Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to define a variable in my regular expression in a way that I can simply extract its corresponding value from matched input string.

For example, I have a pattern like this: `"\w*\s+\d+"`,

And an input string like: `"aaa 113"`

When the matching string is received, I want to be able to simply extract the value corresponds to the part of pattern which says `"\d+"` which is numerical value using C#

Need to mention that I am storing expressions in a database table and I want to extract variables from matched strings and pass their values to a dynamically retrieved query or stored procedure.

I want to the procedure to be completely context-free as we don't the occurrence place of variables and their values in matching string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use match groups with names without depending on its order in the pattern:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("aaa 113", @"(?<word>\w*)(?<space>\s+)(?<num>\d+)");
string words = match.Groups["word"].Value;              //"aaa"
string spaces = match.Groups["space"].Value;            //" "
string nums = match.Groups["num"].Value;                //"113"
```

Comment: THAT'S IT !!! Thank you very much! I must knew it should have such a simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

That's what [match groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) are for.

With match groups, you can easily extract a substring that matched a *parenthesised subexpression* of your regexp. A pattern would be like `"\w*\s+(\d+)"` (you might want to add anchors `^`, `$` if your intent is to match the whole string).

When you have a substring, it's still up to you to convert it to numerical value if that's what you want (using `int.Parse` or something like that).